# Getting complex data from one Dataframe into another

Tags: r

I am relatively new to R and I have got the hang of handling data which is within a single data frame. But for my requirement now, I am facing an issue which I have explained below:

1. I have a data frame DD1.df which contains the following data:

[image: First Dataframe]

I have another data frame DD2.df which contains the following data:

[image: Second Dataframe]

I want to add a column in DD1.df called Delivered Count and calculate the values from the second Data frame of how many orders were delivered.

Please note that that column "order.Description" in first data frame is unstructured text and can be empty and contain verbose text with the order nos.

Can someone help me out here? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go. We use `str_extract_all` from the package `stringr` to extract all orders - defined by the string ORD followed by 5 digits. Note that you need to modify the 2nd argument of `str_extract_all` in case other patterns need to define a valid order. `separate_rows` from the `tidyr` package is used to separate multiple orders into their own row. Finally we count the number of total and delivered orders.

```
df1 <- data.frame(
  Country = c("France", "England", "India", "America", "England"),
  City = c("Paris", "London", "Mumbai", "Los Angeles", "London"),
  Order_Desc = c("No order was placed", "ORD-34212 was the order placed",
                 "ORD-12252 and ORD-78564 was the order placed",
                 "The orders placed before 2017 was ORD-56438, ORD-13198
                 and ORD-12258", "The order was ORD-34567"),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
  )
df2 <- data.frame(
  OrderNo = c("ORD-34212", "ORD-12252", "ORD-78564", "ORD-56438",
              "ORD-13198", "ORD-12258", "ORD-34567"),
  Status = c("Delivered", "Not delivered", "Not delivered",
             "Delivered", "Not delivered", "Delivered", "Delivered"),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1g <- df1 %>%
  group_by(Country, City) %>%
  mutate(
    orders = paste(str_extract_all(Order_Desc, "ORD-\\d{5}", simplify = TRUE),
                   collapse = "|")
  ) %>%
  distinct(Country, City, orders) %>%
  separate_rows(orders, sep = "[|]") %>%
  left_join(df2, by = c("orders" = "OrderNo"))
df1s <- df1g %>%
  group_by(Country, City) %>%
  summarise(
    total_orders = sum(!is.na(Status)),
    delivered_orders = sum(Status == "Delivered")
  )
```

Comment: Wow! Just wow radmuzom! Thanks a lot for your reply. This solves my problem perfectly. I now need to study up on these functions and packages you have used. So far, I have not used "tidyr"; will read up now.

Comment: Thanks. If this works for you, kindly choose this as the accepted answer.

Comment: Accepted and Voted up! Thanks again.

Comment: I have run into another issue when there is repeated data in df1. For example, if there is another entry for (England, London) and a new order is mentioned; then I am getting a wrong output. Any suggestions?

Comment: I don’t have access to R right now but existing code should work - as we are grouping by country and city. So we should get a unique row for each combination in the final summary.

Comment: #radmuzom, can you please try it out when you get access? Assume df1 has another row entry with ("England", "London", "ORD-34567") and df2 has another entry ("ORD-34567", "Delivered").... then the output in df1s for london comes as total_orders = 4 and delivered_orders = 4 when it should be 2 and 2.  Sorry for the trouble again but can you check when you do get access to R. Thanks again; your suggestions would be much appreciated here.

Comment: Edited the answer to make it more general